# How to consume native-code(windows) from HTML5

Tags: javascript, windows, html, dll

I am quite new in HTML5 and I am looking for docs and examples in relation to access to native code from HTML5 app. 
Basically, I have a compile **dll** that need to be access by HTML5 code.

Comment: Look into Google Native Client.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to do this directly from HTML5. HTML5 is a mark-up language, used to denote structure and content in a semantically correct way. To access anything programmatically from it, you need to use an additional language. JavaScript is used client side, where as a server-side language will need to be used to access something like a dll file.

tl;dr -- This is not possible using only HTML5.

Comment: HTML5 is technically a markup language, however it is widely used in a more broad sense to encompass all of the new technologies surrounding web development, which includes java. Perhaps the user is confused by this broad scope.

Answer (score 6):

That's completely impossible.

Sorry.

Comment: Last time someone said that in computers...they got hacked. Nothing is impossible! Just very unlikely.

Comment: @AwDogsGo2Heaven: He asked how to do it in HTML5, not security holes.